# How to filter Hakyll posts with a custom metadata

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I would like to filter some posts of my website based on a metadata value. I would like to create a specific metadata called `status` (like `title` or `date`) which could take several values (draft, published, archive) :

```
---
title: The title
author: Myself
date: 2016-11-29
tags: tag1, tag2
status: draft
---
```

According to the value of the `status` metadata, the post should be published or not.

I have a look in the hackage  [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.12.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Core-Metadata.html) but I'm not sure of the functions to use.

**Do you know how to make that with Hakyll ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`matchMetadata`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.12.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Core-Rules.html#v:matchMetadata):

```
matchMetadata :: Pattern -> (Metadata -> Bool) -> Rules () -> Rules ()
```

With it, instead of, say...

```
match "posts/*.md" $ do -- etc.
```

... you might have:

```
matchMetadata "posts/*.md" (\m -> lookupString "status" m == Just "published") $ do -- etc.
```